# How to customize a merge request message on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

Before starting a new issue, I always create a new branch for it (directly from Gitlab). When I finish the job on that issue (and tests are Ok), I create a merge request (from Gitlab).

After the merge is done, I have an "*auto-generated*" message linked to that merge (this message is very generic and identical to all merges I done).

The some thing happens also when I merge `develop` into `master`:

[image]

Is there a way to customize the merge request message to have a message like this:

- Merge {*shortIssueName*}: {*issueDescription*} into {develop|master}

Note:

- I'm using GitLab Community Edition 8.15.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Globally, automatically - I don't think so. As I see, [it's hard-coded](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/merge_request.rb#L632):

> ```
> message = [
>   "Merge branch '#{source_branch}' into '#{target_branch}'",
>   title
> ]
>
> if !include_description && closes_issues_references.present?
>   message << "Closes #{closes_issues_references.to_sentence}"
> end
>
> message << "#{description}" if include_description && description.present?
> message << "See merge request #{to_reference}"
>
> message.join("\n\n")
> ```

You can override message for any merge request manually:

[image]

It's also possible if you [create merge request with API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#create-mr). It requires your time but you can build some mechanism that fetches all data with API and set it as a description (but you must ensure all is available with API, issueDescription and so on).

Comment: Good and precise answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is anything new by now?

Comment: Seems like since Gitlab 14.5, customizing merge and squash commit messages are supported, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/commit_templates.html

Answer (score 2):

Even tho @piotr-dawidiuk makes a good point, I believe is outdated.

According to gitlab docs, you can create your `.md` files, changing all templates. [Check it here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#creating-merge-request-templates). As it states,

> Similarly to issue templates, create a new Markdown (.md) file inside the .gitlab/merge_request_templates/ directory in your repository. Commit and push to your default branch.

Comment: This customizes what someone writes in the MR description shown on the page, not the commit message. It does get you really close to the desired effect if you check the "Include merge request description" checkbox, which is visible when you act to modify the commit message, as shown in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/img/squash_mr_message.png.